# getPluginDefinition custom QueueWorker empty after upgrade

Tags: cron, 10, queue

I've got a custom queue worker that used to work fine in Drupal 9, but stopped working after the upgrade to Drupal 10.

I've narrowed it down to the getPluginDefinition method not returning anything. So in the core Cron.php I get a warning on the following line:

```
$lease_time = $worker->getPluginDefinition()['cron']['time'];
```

If I comment out this line, and just set the $lease_time to 1 my QueueWorker works fine. Clearly the worker itself is OK, but getting the meta data fails for some reason.

This is what my class definition looks like:

```
namespace Drupal\module_send_pdf\Plugin\QueueWorker;

use Drupal\Core\Mail\MailManagerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Queue\QueueWorkerBase;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * A Mail Sender that sends e-mails on CRON run.
 * 
 * @QueueWorker(
 *   id = "module_pdf_mail_sender",
 *   title = @Translation("PDF Mail Sender"),
 *   cron = {"time" = 105}
 * )
 */
class MailSender extends QueueWorkerBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {

protected $mailManager;

  public function __construct(MailManagerInterface $mail_manager) {
    $this->mailManager = $mail_manager;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {

    return new static(
      $container->get('plugin.manager.mail')
    );
  }
```

As far as I can tell that markup is OK. So what am I missing?

Comment: Seems like an issue with your dependency injection given your implementation of `ContainerFactoryPluginInterface`. Can you show us your class constructor and `create()` method?

Comment: @baikho: added constructor and create method. As mentioned though: the class gets instantiated fine. If I ignore the pluginDefinition not returning data my items gets processed.

Comment: IMHO ContainerFactoryPluginInterface in average custom code is not necessary unless you really need it to write test routines. Use \Drupal::service() instead. Refactor the code depending on DI to services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change your constructor and `create()` method to match the `ContainerFactoryPluginInterface` interface for the plugin definition details to be passed to the parent class:

```
  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, array $plugin_definition, MailManagerInterface $mail_manager) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
    $this->mailManager = $mail_manager;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->get('plugin.manager.mail')
    );
  }
```

Comment: That works! Thanks!


The real question is: how did that ever work in Drupal 9?

Comment: Looks like `Cron.php` has underwent some changes in the queue handling and `processQueue()` in D10 does not provide a fallback on the cron time definition. Regardless, if the queue worker subclass adheres to the base class it should work with both core versions.